# Using UsageStatsManager to get the foreground app

Tags: android, usagestatsmanager

I'm trying to use UsageStatsManager to get the foreground app on a Nexus 5 with Marshmallow. I remember it used to work, but for some reason I'm getting null strings for package/class names now.

Here's my implementation

```
public String[] getForegroundPackageNameClassNameByUsageStats() {
    String packageNameByUsageStats = null;
    String classByUsageStats = null;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
        UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService("usagestats");                       
        final long INTERVAL = 1000;
        final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long begin = end - INTERVAL;
        final UsageEvents usageEvents = mUsageStatsManager.queryEvents(begin, end);
        while (usageEvents.hasNextEvent()) {
            UsageEvents.Event event = new UsageEvents.Event();
            usageEvents.getNextEvent(event);
            if (event.getEventType() == UsageEvents.Event.MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND) {
                packageNameByUsageStats = event.getPackageName();
                classByUsageStats = event.getClassName();
                Log.d(TAG, "packageNameByUsageStats is" + packageNameByUsageStats + ", classByUsageStats is " + classByUsageStats);
            }
        }
    }
    return new String[]{packageNameByUsageStats,classByUsageStats};
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't go into the while loop, i.e. usageEvents.hasNextEvent() is false. Because of this, it returns null package/class names.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Mostly one think it works because on testing one likes to switch apps often to check fast if it works. Problems come when the last change in foreground app is longer ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so I found that once I set the interval to 10000 instead of 1000, it works. Apparently a 1s interval is too small.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this myself. I think the usage stats will only be updated when an app comes to foreground. So if the foreground app got to the foreground (and stayed) before your 'begin' timestamp then you will not get it. :(

On the other hand when you use a long time ago you will get a giant list where you only need the highest time to determine the foreground app.

**So what I do is I create 3 different times: 1min ago, 1 hour ago and 12 hours ago.**

When I get an empty list on 1min I repeat request with 1h and so on. That way I get foreground most of the time. But I never get it to work ALL of the time.

I really miss the old way of just asking the package manager which app is foreground (prior to android 5), the new way is a bit messy.